# Build failure: Configuration file not found

Tags: jenkins

I was testing Jenkins out to learn out to deploy from a local repo (using a deploy script) on a remote server through ssh.
I already installed and set up the "Publish over SSH Plugin" to connect and allow files to be transfered to the remote servers.
I created a job and when I built it I encountered a failure. Below is the console output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository file:///home/user/testproject
> git init /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace # timeout=10 
Fetching upstream changes from file:///home/user/testproject
> git --version # timeout=10
> git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress file:///home/user/testproject +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git config remote.origin.url file:///home/user/testproject # timeout=10
> git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> git config remote.origin.url file:///home/user/testproject # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from file:///home/user/testproject
> git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress file:///home/user/testproject +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 1564ecf8d0cab524978ed0686e9199d9f69108b1 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f 1564ecf8d0cab524978ed0686e9199d9f69108b1
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2631034899576944316.sh
+ ./myproject/deploy.sh
========= Starting the deploy utility =========


Project Directory :::  /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
Configuration file not found.
Please create a user configuration in deploy.jenkins.properties
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What's the content of your deploy script ? It's obviously some kind of relative/absolute path problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found the hard coded path. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No issue with Jenkins. Hardcoded path in deploy script.